# Generate a file as a Release Pipeline's output in Azure DevOps?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

During a Release pipeline I need to download a Storage Table content before deleting the resource, but I don't know which path I can save the files to.

I can't save to another Azure resource, more like a Pipeline output, or like the files generated by the Tests.

I tried saving to something like $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) but no success

Answer (score -3):

You can add a [`Copy Files`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=vsts) task to copy the files to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` first, then publish them to build artifacts using `Publish Build Artifacts` task.

You can also copy the files to a file share (UNC path like `\\sharefolder)` if it's an option.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, just a couple of questions: From where is the Copy To task getting the content? Or in other words, I get the content from Storage and save it to ¿? so that the Copy task can take it from there? And where does the Publish Artifact is going to save the file?

Comment: Publish Artifact task throws error: "This task must run in a build to publish artifacts to Visual Studio Team Services/TFS"

Comment: @Velair Yeah, checked that the `Publish Build Artifacts` task not work in release pipeline. So, what about the `UNC` path?